# Is there a way I can read data from an excel file using React Native?

Tags: javascript, excel, react-native

I'm new to react native and I wanted to build an app that takes an excel file as an input and does some calculations based on the contents of the input. How would I approach that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach is rely on a well tested and supported npm package.
Excel js is a good starting point, try looking at the documentation to see if that's what you need
https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs